# Passing dynamic data with click once application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, clickonce

I have a web page where the user provides the input and press the Submit button. On button click I'm downloading the click once application to process the input on client machine. Currently passing the input as query string parameter to the click once application.
i.e. myapp.application?

But there is a limitation in the Query string, that I cannot send the data more than ~2000 characters, Is there any way that I can attach the data along with the download of click Once application?

Comment: Random thought... could you instead pass a URL for the data as a parameter to the ClickOnce application and have it request the full data from your web application?

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce uses manifest file to define, what files should be downloaded. I hope, you are using signed manifest for application deployment. Signed manifest contains package files hashes as well as hash of the manifest itself. You can put the data into the file, which is defined in the manifest. However, you will have to generate manifest file dynamically every time a user requests application installation along with new portion of data. This can work fine, if the user removes the application right after data processing has been finished. But it can easily out of control eventually.

I would try another approach: store the data on server side and put id value into query parameter string. The application can request the data from the server by provided id. Just make sure that the data is protection is consistent with its sensitivity. For example, if it is some kind of private user information or data protected by law, you need to make sure that only authorized user can get it from the server and the data is stored in secure manner.